# Is there a way to close a single window of a process from a BAT file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

Here's my situation:

I have my Windows 7 computer set up so that every morning, a task runs that plays my alarm and causes my morning routine to open up (in a WordPad window). The thing is, I would like to also have the window automatically close at the time when I leave for work so I don't have it cluttering up my desktop after work. After all, if the window is always open, that kind of ruins its purpose as a reminder.

Ideally, I would like a way to close only the WordPad window containing that any other WordPad windows I have open are not affected. Simply killing the task would close all WordPad windows (probably regardless of whether they have unsaved data or not).

So is there a way to close a specific window (not the whole process) from a Windows batch file? Or from anything else I can run from Task Scheduler, I suppose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.  Use `tasklist` to find the window based on its title, then `taskkill` to kill it by PID.

```js
@echo off
setlocal

for /f "skip=3 tokens=2" %%I in (
    'tasklist /fi "windowtitle eq Reminders.rtf - WordPad"'
) do taskkill /im "%%I"
```

Or just

```js
taskkill /fi "windowtitle eq Reminders.rtf - WordPad"
```

Comment: On the one hand, the question specifically asked how to close a window - *not* kill an entire process (which may own many windows). On the other hand, Wordpad only does one document and window per process so this would work.

Comment: Thats the difference between SDI and MDI

Comment: Why would you not just use `taskkill /fi "windowtitle eq Reminders.rtf - WordPad"`. That sends a `WM_CLOSE` message to the specified window.